# Numbering Rows within two different, joined tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables, but I have read-only access, so I can't CREATE or UPDATE any tables:

- issue (table for issues in the system)

| id (PK) |
| --- |
| issue-1 |
| issue-2 |
| issue-3 |

- changegroup (table to group change logs)

| id (PK) | issueid (FK) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | issue-1 |
| 2 | issue-1 |
| 3 | issue-1 |
| 4 | issue-2 |
| 5 | issue-2 |
| 6 | issue-3 |

- changeitem (table for change logs; there can be multiple changeitem records connected to one changegroup)

| id (PK) | groupid (FK) | field |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | status |
| 2 | 1 | status |
| 3 | 1 | comment |
| 4 | 1 | summary |
| 5 | 2 | status |
| 6 | 2 | priority |
| 7 | 3 | status |
| 8 | 3 | status |
| 9 | 3 | priority |
| 10 | 3 | comment |
| 6 | 3 | status |
| 7 | 4 | status |
| 8 | 4 | comment |

In the issue table, the ids shown are the primary keys. There are tens of thousands of records and several other fields but the ones display are just an example of the primary key.

In the changegroup table, the id is the primary key for that table, but the issueid field is a foreign key from the issues table.

In the changeitem table, the id is the primary key for that table, but the groupid field is a foreign key from the changegroup table.

issue.id --> changegroup.issueid

changegroup.id --> changeitem.groupid

It may be worth noting that the changeitem table houses all change logs for every possible change made to an issue.  There are tens of thousands of records in the changeitem table because it stores all the changes (e.g., status updates, comments added, description change, priority change, assignment, etc.).

Here's what I want the results to look like:

| cg_row | ci_row | iss_issueid | field |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | issue-1 | status |
| 2 | 1 | issue-2 | status |
| 2 | 2 | issue-2 | status |
| 2 | 3 | issue-2 | status |
| 3 | 1 | issue-3 | status |
| 3 | 2 | issue-3 | status |

How do I create those rows like that? Here's my current query:

```
 
select
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY cg.issueid) as cg_row
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ci.id) as ci_row
        , iss.id as iss_issueid
        ,ci.field as field
from
        issue iss
        left join issuestatus st on iss.issuestatus = st.id
        left join changegroup cg on iss.id = cg.issueid
        left join changeitem ci on ci.groupid = cg.id 
where
       ci.field = 'status'
order by 
        cg_row, cg_row asc;
```

But instead of what I was looking for above, it's returning this:

| cg_row | ci_row | iss_issueid | field |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 281 | issue-1 | status |
| 2 | 283 | issue-2 | status |
| 2 | 326 | issue-2 | status |
| 2 | 368 | issue-2 | status |
| 3 | 289 | issue-3 | status |
| 3 | 346 | issue-3 | status |

The row numbers on the second column are counting the row for that entire table, not just ones connected to the changegroup rank. So it looks like when I add ROW_NUMBER() it adds a row number for every record, not just the ones that have 'status' as the field or is directly connected to a record in changegroup (all records in changeitem are connected to a record in changegroup).

If I change the statement like this:

```
select
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY cg.issueid) as cg_row
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ci.id) as ci_row
        , iss.id as iss_issueid
        , ci.field as field
from
        issue iss
        left join changegroup cg on iss.id = cg.issueid
        left join changeitem ci on ci.groupid = cg.id 
where
        ci.field = 'status'
order by 
        cg_row, cg_row asc;
```

Then it now returns:

| cg_row | ci_row | iss_issueid | field |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | issue-1 | status |
| 2 | 1 | issue-2 | status |
| 2 | 1 | issue-2 | status |
| 2 | 1 | issue-2 | status |
| 3 | 1 | issue-3 | status |
| 3 | 1 | issue-3 | status |

How do I structure the query to get the results I'm looking for?

Comment: With the data and query you provided, postgres returns a different result than the one you get. I suspect you have edited the query for your question + that there are records you are hiding (I suppose, `id`s that exist in 1 table but not in others, making your `left join`s behave in a way you do not expect + since you shared no info about foreign keys, we have no way to be sure this case is possible) and that makes the issue not reproducible. The same goes for your expected result: how could you possibly expect to get `issue-4` when such value appears nowhere in your data?

Comment: BTW, your `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (...)` is missing a `PARTITION BY iss.id` to make it restart from 1 every time `iss.id` changes between 2 consecutive rows.

Comment: The tables I shared are edits, and they are not the complete table. The fact that it goes to issue-4 is irrelevant because there are thousands of records in all of these tables, but I'm not going to format that many tables in the Stack Overflow input field for questions. I am updating the question to indicate where there are foreign keys.

Comment: @Atmo I updated the question to call out more of the specifics concerning the tables, the records, etc.. I had tried PARTITION BY first, but instead of the row numbers being 1, 2, 3, etc. it shows them as 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, etc across the board. Based on your previous statement, the issue might be that the records tied to each individual cg_row or issue are not consecutive in the changeitem table.

Comment: I said to `PARTITION BY iss.id` was missing so I expected you would **add** it to the window clause. You have **replaced** (1st mistake) what you had with `PARTITION BY ci.id` (2nd mistake: wrong field).

Comment: I changed the partition to PARTITION BY iss.id, ci.id but the new records were out of order based on ci.id. I corrected this by changing it to PARTITION BY iss.id ORDER BY ci.id. This appeared to have worked because now the ci.id's are in the right order and the columns look correct now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I was partitioning the rows by the wrong field. I corrected the query to `PARTITION BY iss.id`, but then it was showing the `ci.id out` of order. I added `ORDER BY ci.id` and it now partitions correctly and is in the correct order:

```
select
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY cg.issueid) as cg_row
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY iss.id ORDER BY ci.id) as ci_row
    , iss.id as iss_issueid
    , ci.field as field
from
    issue iss
    left join changegroup cg on iss.id = cg.issueid
    left join changeitem ci on ci.groupid = cg.id 
where
    ci.field = 'status'
order by 
    cg_row, cg_row asc;
```